# ! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I tried to deploy my Django application on Heroku. But it shows an error. Then I install pywin32 by command- "pip install pypiwin32". It did not work. Please help me to solve this problem.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==303 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==303
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

Comment: yes, who knows why this error happens, I fixed it by removing the pywin